# Cambiar tamaño a atributo title en img

Tags: jquery, css

Buen dia a todos, tengo un grupo de  imagenes de la siguiente manera:

```html
<img id="img_1" title="Imagen 1" src="">
<img id="img_2" title="Imagen 2" src="">
<img id="img_3" title="Imagen 3" src="">
<img id="img_4" title="Imagen 4" src="">
<img id="img_5" title="Imagen 5" src="">
```

Lo que estoy buscando, es si conocen alguna manera de cambiar el tamaño del atributo title. Ya sea con css, jquery, o javascript.

Se los agradezco.

Comment: No queda claro a qué te refieres con cambiar el tamaño

Comment: directamente al title no, me imagino que quieres ver si se le puede agrandar la letra o poner color, pero hay alternativas, revisa las soluciones que dieron en este link, alguna te puede servir. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672946/styling-an-image-title-attribute-using-css). Saludos

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices, quiero cambiarle el color o agrandar la letra, estoy checando el link q pusiste. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Con `font-size` de css se puede hacer lo siguiente.

```css
img[title]{
 color:red;
 font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img_1" title="Imagen 1" src="">
<img id="img_2" title="Imagen 2" src="">
<img id="img_3" title="Imagen 3" src="">
<img id="img_4" title="Imagen 4" src="">
<img id="img_5" title="Imagen 5" src="">
```